# Concatenar archivos txt recibidos desde el terminal y pasados a una función usando fstream en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo C++ y no domino el uso de fstream para el tratamiento de archivos de texto. El resto de alumnos usa windows y los ejercicios los hacen sin usar fstream con lo que estoy en modo autodidacta, ayuda por favor.

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio: *"Programa que concatena, en el archivo indicado por el primer argumento de la línea de órdenes, los archivos indicados en los siguientes argumentos de la línea de órdenes."*

Esto lo debe hacer una función.

Así que, desde el terminal (¡Linux!) se escribirá:
./nombrearchivo archivo1.txt archivo2.txt archivo3.txt

Debo comprobar que almenos hay 3 archivos.
Leer el contenido de archivo2.txt y archivo3.txt y añadirlos al contenido de archivo1.txt.

El primer problema que tengo es que, en Linux, o pongo la ruta absoluta a los archivos o no los encuentra. Así que tengo que añadir la ruta al nombre de archivo que me pasan (¿alguna solución?).

Yo lo que tengo es lo siguiente (que compila pero no funciona, al ejecutarse peta quedándose congelado):

```
//VARIABLES GLOBALES
ifstream leer;
ofstream escribir;

//la función recibirá cada parámetro ya con la ruta absoluta al archivo en cuestión
//así cómo el número de archivos detectado
void concatena(char *argv[], int elementos);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char argv_aux[100]; //string auxiliar para almacenar el nombre del archivo para luego unirlo a la ruta absoluta

    int cuenta_elementos=0; //contador para conocer el numero de archivos recibidos y pasarlo a la función

    //constante con la ruta absoluta para unir al nombre de cada archivo
    const char ruta_absoluta[100]="/Insti/M03_PROGRAMACION/ficheros/";

    //compruevo que por lo menos se reciben 3 archivos  
    if(argc<3){
        cout<< "Error, numero de parametros insuficiente" << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    //i empieza por 1 para no recoger el nombre del ejecutable
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){

        strcpy(argv_aux,argv[i]);   //salvo el nombre del archivo
        strcpy(argv[i], ruta_absoluta); //el nombre del archivo recibido es ahora la ruta absoluta
        strcat(argv[i], argv_aux);  //concateno la ruta absoluta al nombre de archivo y ya tengo la ruta absoluta al archivo

        cuenta_elementos++;
    }

    //envío los archivos(rutas) y el numero total a la función
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){

        concatena(&argv[i], cuenta_elementos);

    }


    escribir.close();
    leer.close();

    return 0;
}

void concatena(char *argv[], int elementos){

    char c; //para leer caracter a caracter

    //abro el archivo original en modo añadir
    escribir.open(argv[0], ios::app);

    for(int i=1; i<elementos; i++){
        //abro el archivo siguiente en modo leer
        leer.open(argv[i], ios::in);

        while(!leer.eof()){

            leer >> c;  //leo un caracter

            escribir<< c;   //lo escribo en el archivo original
        }
    }

}
```

Muchas gracias,
perdón si mi código es un disparate, no sé más,
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En resumen tu programa debe copiar datos de un origen (un archivo) en un destino (otro archivo); esta tarea está generalizada en la función [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), que recibe dos iteradores de lectura (dónde epezar y dónde acabar la lectura) y uno de escritura (dónde escribir).

Podemos acceder a los iteradores al contenido de archivos incluyendo la cabecera [`<iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator), para hacer menos tediosa la escritura de código yo haría un par de alias:

```
using ilectura = std::istream_iterator<char>;
using iescritura = std::ostream_iterator<char>;
```

Los `std::istream_iterator` son iteradores de entrada (`i`nput) de datos desde un flujo (`stream`), los `std::ostream_iterator` son iteradores de salida (`o`utput) de datos a un flujo (`stream`).

Esto puede usarse en una función de concatenado:

```
void concatena_archivos(std::string destino, std::string origen1, std::string origen2)
{
    using ilectura = std::istream_iterator<char>;
    using iescritura = std::ostream_iterator<char>;

    if (std::ofstream resultado{destino})
    {
        if (std::ifstream origen{origen1})
        {
            std::copy(ilectura(origen), ilectura(), iescritura(resultado));
        }
        if (std::ifstream origen{origen2})
        {
            std::copy(ilectura(origen), ilectura(), iescritura(resultado));
        }
    }
}
```

Las sentencias `if (std::ofstream resultado{destino})`
 e `if (std::ifstream origen{origen1})` están usando un *truco* de C++ y un *truco* relacionado con los flujos de datos a archivos:

- En una sentencia `if` puedes declarar una variable, esta variable existirá sólo en el cuerpo del `if` y se convertirá su valor a booleano para saber si debe o no debe entrasre en el cuerpo del `if`.
- Los flujos de datos son convertibles a booleano (valor verdadero o falso) y tendrán un valor falso si sucedió un error al usarlos.

Así que en una sola línea, estamos abriendo un archivo para su escritura (`std::ofstream`) o lectura (`std::ifstream`) y si hay algún fallo en el proceso no haremos nada.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4MZRi1Kv2CBPv1HL).

> El primer problema que tengo es que, en Linux, o pongo la ruta absoluta a los archivos o no los encuentra. Así que tengo que añadir la ruta al nombre de archivo que me pasan (¿alguna solución?).

El problema que describes, suele suceder cuando el directorio de ejecuicón del programa es diferente a la ruta en que se encuentran los datos. Si ambos directorios son el mismo, no tendrás ese problema.

Para acabar:

> Estoy aprendiendo C++ y no domino el uso de fstream para el tratamiento de archivos de texto. El resto de alumnos usa windows y los ejercicios los hacen sin usar fstream con lo que estoy en modo autodidacta

En primer lugar bienvenido al lenguaje C++, puede parecer un mundo enorme y abrumador, pero para esto está SOes :)

El sistema operativo que el resto de compañeros tuyos usen, no debería afectar en nada para el tipo de programa que estás creando y aunque no puedo afirmarlo con total seguridad sin ver sus códigos, si no están usando `std::fstream` para un ejercicio de C++ que implica el uso de archivos, están haciendo el ejercicio mal.

Comment: Súper respuesta!
Aprendí muchas cosas en una respuesta que ni hemos visto en meses de clase, cómo: uso de alias, librería iterator, uso de un stream como condición booleana en un if o herramientas cómo Wandbox.
En clase no usan fstream para ficheros, solo usan fopen y cosas de borland que no van en Linux. Mis compañeros ni saben que es std, nunca se utilizó nada de std en clase, ni siquiera cout o cin, todo lo tengo que aprender yo autodidacta gracias a respuestas cómo esta y otras que hice en SO internacional.
Lo de la ruta no me va así, lo tengo en el mismo dir y no va, solo con absoluta.

Comment: Si en clase no se está utilziando la librería estándar (std) ni la librería de plantillas ([stl](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)) y para colmo se están usando herramientas de [tag:c] como `fopen`, mi opinión es que están enseñando [tag:c++] mal, muy mal. Sobre tu problema de rutas, no me cuadra nada ¿Has probado `ejecutable a b c` en lugar de `./ejecutable a b c`?

Comment: sí, solo usan fopen, fputs, fwrite... stl ni sé lo que es.
No entiendo que me quieres decir. Yo compilo con un Makefile con g++ así: http://oi65.tinypic.com/nvtpgz.jpg y en ese mismo directorio dónde va el fuente y el ejecutable tengo los archivos a tratar. Sin ruta abs no va.
Tras hacer make en el terminal, siempre ejecuto siempre con: ./nombreejecutable
si escribiera solo nombreejecutable sin ./ linux me daría error de comando no reconocido. Así que no entiendo cómo me dices que ejecute y pase parámetros de nombre archivos. Ver: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2m68wi8.jpg

Comment: Te he pasado un enlace a lo que es stl en el comentario anterior. No voy a abrir los enlaces a tus imágenes porque el primero que he abierto me han salido cochinadas y estoy en el trabajo. ¿Has probado `./ejecutable ./a ./b ./c`?

Comment: Perdon por lo de las imágenes, utilizé el primer host de imágenes que encontré en google (estoy en clase).
Vale! sí, así:
./ejecutable ./a ./b ./c
Sí funciona!
Gracias, y disculpa.

Answer (score 3):

> Estoy aprendiendo C++ y no domino el uso de fstream para el tratamiento de archivos de texto. El resto de alumnos usa windows y los ejercicios los hacen sin usar fstream con lo que estoy en modo autodidacta, ayuda por favor.

El uso de `fstream` no está limitado de ninguna manera a Sistemas Operativos Linux. Es una clase que forma parte del estándar de C++, lo que implica que estará disponible en **todas** las plataformas.

Esa primera frase con la que empiezas la pregunta carece totalmente de sentido.

> Yo lo que tengo es lo siguiente (que compila pero no funciona, al ejecutarse peta quedándose congelado):

El programa puede o *petar* o quedarse *congelado*... no puede hacer las dos cosas al mismo tiempo:

- Si *peta* entonces aparecerá un error lanzado por el Sistema Operativo y el programa finalizará
- Si se queda *congelado* el programa se ejecutará indefinidamente hasta que decidas pararlo por aburrimiento o porque se ha consumido toda la energía del universo.

Dejando de lado estas incoherencias, veamos:

```
    strcpy(argv_aux,argv[i]);   //salvo el nombre del archivo
    strcpy(argv[i], ruta_absoluta); //el nombre del archivo recibido es ahora la ruta absoluta
    strcat(argv[i], argv_aux);  //concateno la ruta absoluta al nombre de archivo y ya tengo la ruta absoluta al archivo
```

En estas tres líneas de código, la segunda llama poderosamente la atención. Los parámetros de entrada deberían ser **de solo lectura**. Es decir, es posible modificar ese array, pero no tienen ningún sentido:

- Si excedes el tamaño del array acabarás sobreescribiendo otras regiones de memoria
- Los cambios realizados no se reflejarán fuera del programa

Es decir, no hay razón para que la segunda línea haga cambios sobre dichos parámetros. ¿Por qué motivo haces eso? Si tu idea es usar una ruta absoluta podías haber hecho lo siguiente:

```
strcpy(argv_aux, ruta_absoluta);
strcat(argv_aux, argv[i]);
```

O incluso

```
sprintf(argv_aux, "%s%s", ruta_absoluta, argv[i]);
```

O, ya que estamos en C++, podemos hasta usar clases propias de C++:

```
std::string const ruta_absoluta = "/Insti/M03_PROGRAMACION/ficheros/";
std::string ruta = ruta_absoluta + argv[i];
```

Ya que el hecho de que `fstream` requiera que le pases la ruta en un puntero a `char` no te impide usar `std::string`:

```
std::fstream file(ruta.c_str(), ios_base::out);
//                     ~~~~~ Metodo para acceder a la memoria interna del string
```