# Pasar datos de fichero a matriz en c++

Tags: c++

Soy muy nuevo en C++, y os quería consultar cuál sería la mejor manera de leer un archivo, y extraer los números de este y convertirlos en matriz. ¿Cómo puedo transformar los string a números independientes mediante cada salto de línea?

Adjunto el código mediante el cual abro el archivo.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void lectura();


int main(){
    lectura();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}void lectura(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;
    fopen("nile",ios::in);

    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se puede abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!archivo.eof()){
        getline(archivo,texto);

    }




    archivo.close();
}
```

También decir que los datos están en notación científica, ¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de reemplazar la e del formato de string al formato númerico?

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cómo puedo transformar los string a números?

Usa [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::strinstream ss("1234567890")
int numero;
ss >> numero;
```

Para facilitar la tarea, yo redactaría una función plantilla:

```
template <typename T = double>
T convierte(const std::string &numero)
{
    std::stringstream sstream(numero);
    T valor;
    sstream >> valor;
    return valor;
}
```

Puede usarse así:

```
std::cout << convierte<int>("1234567890") << '\n';
std::cout << convierte<int>("99 Luftballoons") << '\n';
std::cout << (long)convierte("6e+10") << '\n';
std::cout << convierte("6e-10") << '\n';
std::cout << convierte<int>("1234567890123456789") << '\n';
std::cout << convierte<long long>("1234567890123456789") << '\n';
```

Las líneas anteriores muestran:

> ```
> 1234567890
> 99
> 60000000000
> 6e-10
> 2147483647
> 1234567890123456789
> ```

Puedes ver que procesa como número cualquier cadena que empiece por número ([`"99 Luftballoons"`](https://youtu.be/La4Dcd1aUcE) lo interpreta como `99`), que lee notación científica (`6e10` lo interpreta como un seis seguido de diez ceros) y que hace lo que puede cuando el numero pasado no cabe en el tipo facilitado (`1234567890123456789` es mayor que la capacidad de `int`, así que almacena el número mayor que puede almacenar).

Respecto a leer línea a línea, ya lo estás haciendo, pero tu código puede ser más compacto:

```
void lectura(){
    using namespace std;

    if (ifstream archivo{"nile"}){
        string texto;

        while (!getline(archivo, texto).eof()){
            auto valor = convierte(texto);
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "No se puede abrir el archivo";
    }
}
```

Consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/28365/2742) y [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/250708/2742), para entender las modificaciones que te propongo.

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas la documentación de [`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), verás que implementa el [`operador de extracción`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) y que el mismo esta sobrecargado para leer, entre otras cosas, números. Su uso es trivial:

```
float numero;
archivo >> numero;
```

Ignoro cómo quieres almacenar la matriz en el fichero, pero suponiendo que los números se separen por espacios la lectura es realmente sencilla:

fichero:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

código:

```
float matriz[3][3];
for(int f = 0; f<3; f++ )
{
  for( int c=0; c<3; c++ )
    archivo >> matriz[f][c];
}


for(int f = 0; f<3; f++ )
{
  for( int c=0; c<3; c++ )
    std::cout << matriz[f][c] << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```